# What type of paint should I use to decorate a kitchen appliance?

Tags: paint, medium-selection

I got a blender for a present, and its body is black plastic. Because of a family joke, we'd like to paint some purple decorations on it. This is inspired by very artistic hand painted stand mixers have seen, such as:

[image: Mixer with floral design painted on]

I'm not sure what type of paint to use for this project. What will smoothly and cleanly cover appliance plastic, and not wear away over time (considering it may be regularly handled, and also need light washing on occasion)?

Comment: Do you have a particular budget in mind for this?

Comment: Not really (although if only very high-end paints will do, I may not bother)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are special paints for plastic. If there is nothing in the colour you want, you may use plastic paint as primer/undercoat and use acrylic paint on top of that.
Be aware that plastic has a very smooth surface, so you have to sand it first in order to give the paint some texture to hold.
You may also want to apply a layer of lacquer as a finish, for extra durability.

Comment: Are they just called "plastic paints" or something specific? What sanding grit granularity is bent? Is any old lacquer okay?

Comment: Brands that I found are Krylon and Plastidip, but I'm sure they're not the only ones. As for sanding, use fine granularity (e.g. 180 grit). The plastic should not be shiny anymore after sanding. And finally, the lacquer should at least be something to go with the paint.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to painting on plastic, is to reduce the static electricity.  This can be done with a damp rag leaning against the object.  Once the static charge is controlled you can paint with enamels. Enamel finish will be semi-permanent, need no primer, washable, and glossy.  You'll also have a variety of colors which mix and blend readily.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a stencil using cardboard and then buy cheap ceramic spray paint cans. ceramic spray is perfect & stencils are fun.

Comment: Cardboard might be hard to use for a template on a contoured surface. Ceramic paint is still a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, epoxy is the indestructible, and permanent,  it is difficult to use, an expensive.  But it is the best solution.  IMHO

Comment: Epoxy? As in glue? Could you explain the product you are describing to help make your answer more useful?